# Datepickerpopup from Ui Bootstrap doesn't show calendar icon

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular2-ui-bootstrap

I am following the tutorial from [Ui Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). The code is exactly the same as [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview).
If I replace this `css line` (`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`) with local (`<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`), the calender icon disappear as shown in the image. I copy the exact `bootstrap.min.css` and put into local css folder. What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please check glyphicon style and font family included in your html

Comment: Check inside `bootstrap.min.css` and make sure the paths to the glyphicon fonts are pointing to the correct URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will open your console you will find out that the requests for the glyphicon fonts returned 404 (NOT_FOUND) because the local .css files tries to locate these files relatively to where it's at (local script rather than hosted on a cdn).

[image]

To resolve this, you will also have to include the glyphicons files locally

Another option is to abandon glyphicons altogether and use something like font awesome or octicons because bootstrap 4 will remove glyphicons.